# Matlab GUIDE blurs image?

Tags: image, matlab, blur, matlab-guide

my plan is implementing an image in a Matlab GUIDE figure. Somehow the output is always blurred (see screenshot). On the left you can see the image in Photoshop on the right in Matlab - notice how the font and other parts become blurred.
I experimented with JPEG and PNG file formats (no compression), I also tried various pixel sizes(resolutions smaller, same and bigger as the actual position of the image) and DPI(values between 30-300) settings, because I expected some scaling issue. Somehow I am stuck - Looking forward to your input!

Thank you,
Florian

Screenshot of the issue: http://s1.bild.me/bilder/260513/6875414Screen_Shot_2014-06-29_at_23.19.34.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably the reason for the blur is interpolation.
If the axis size you allocated for the image is different from the size of the image MATLAB will resize the image to occupy the whole area.

In order to prevent any interpolation you must set the axis dimension to be the image dimension.

Comment: how can I do that? How can I find out the exact axis dimension to build the image accordingly and prevent the scaling?

Comment: Look at the `axes` documentation: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes.html. More specifically look at its properties: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes_props.html. Look for the dimension property.

Comment: Hmm I don't find a dimension property. However I found "OuterPosition" and "Position" which both contain a width and height property. What unit are those and which one is right one or is it the completely wrong way?

Comment: Yea, I meant "Position". Use pixels in the `Units` property.